# Removing a word from a <p> only using css

Tags: css, cpu-word

Due to mod rights on a site, I can only add css (no js etc...). When users input text in a comment box, it saves it and then displays it as a `<p>`. is there any way through css i can search for a specific word in the `<p>` tag and remove/censor it?

Thanks

Comment: CSS is about format, not content.  You can't do this using CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no practical solution for that ( You may be able to select elements based on the value and hide them in CSS3 but it wouldn't be cross-browser friendly, if at all possible ). I'm afraid you'll have to use JS/server-side for a **real** solution.

On the hacky side of things and for IE only, you may be able to use an `expression` and `display:none` elements which contain certain strings in their nodeValue, it wouldn't work for modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If parent element in this case input field has class or id you can hide elements inside like this

```css
textarea#mytextarea p
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was attempting, however there doesn't seem to be a way to search for a particular word!

Answer (score -1):

- Once upon a time, there was a [pseudo-class :contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors)  in the wonderful spec of CSS3 selectors ... but it disappeared early and afaik well before any implementation.
- A JS solution has one problem: search bots and any user without JS (or displaying the source code) will see the f***ing original text :)